AutoMapper - Flatten the HTTP response to my desired class
I have the model classes that my HTTP response will be deserialized.
public class Contract
{
    public IEnumerable<InnerClass> MyConfig { get; set; }
}

public class InnerClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

I want to map it to a flatter class
public class MyClass
{
    public int IdWithDifferentName { get; set; }
    public string ValueWithDifferentName { get; set; }
}

My challenge is that the response is an array, so effectively I get IEnumerable<Contract> which I then want to map to an IEnumerable<MyClass>, which should contain all InnerClass values, regardless of which instance of Contract it came from.
What do I need to do in AutoMapper to get this to work?
This is how I call AutoMapper:
var configs = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(response);


If you are looking to implement the conversion logic in the AutoMapper mapping profile/rule, you need:

Mapping rule for InnerClass to MyClass.

Mapping rule for Contract to IEnumerable<MyClass>.

Mapping rule for IEnumerable<Contract> to IEnumerable<MyClass>.


CreateMap<InnerClass, MyClass>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IdWithDifferentName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ValueWithDifferentName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));

CreateMap<Contract, IEnumerable<MyClass>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dest, context) => context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(src.MyConfig));

CreateMap<IEnumerable<Contract>, IEnumerable<MyClass>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, dest, context) => src.SelectMany(x => context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(x.MyConfig)));

Reference: Custom Type Converters

Demo @ .NET Fiddle

Thank you! This was definitely cleaner than what ChapGPT suggested

After working a lot with chat GPT (and a lot of trial and error) we reached a working solution.
I needed to do a regular, basic map of InnerClass to MyClass and then change the way I was calling it to
var configs = response.SelectMany(c => c.MyConfig).Select(inner => _mapper.Map<MyClass>(inner));

and then it worked

Instead of using ChatGPT you should really read AutoMapper's Design Philosophy because you're misusing it to the point of uselessness. What did AutoMapper offer you here that wasn't already provided by a simple .Select(inner=>new MyClass{IdWithDifferentName =inner.Id,...}) ? If AutoMapper's creator says "don't do that", or "no, it's not for that" ....

Thanks for the article! I have read it but do not understand exactly how I am misusing it - I still use it to map InnerClass to MyClass, but my problem was flattening the IEnumberable that was the response. Had I just gotten a single contract I would not have had the problem

You aren't flattening anything, you're converting a list of classes to another list of classes with different property names.  You could have used _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(response.MyConfig) but there's no way to use any naming conventions for names that violate the naming conventions. The AutoMapper configuration code you have to write  is more complex than a simple .Select or return new and stored far away from the point it's actually used. You could have used an extension method or a conversion method on one of the classes instead.

Interesting. I am not sure I fully understand but will look more into it. Meanwhile I have accepted Yong Shun's answer since it is cleaner and more reusable than what I had initially - and it implements what is needed using AutoMapper instead of the SelectMany in the service

But not cleaner than just a .Select(inner=>new MyClass{IdWithDifferentName =inner.Id,...}). You don't need AutoMapper at all here. Why are you using it in the first place?

The reason I am using AutoMapper is to fit the team's existing conventions
